# Stop motion video on Ubuntu

Tags: video-capture, ubuntu-12.10, multimedia

Is there a software to create a stop motion video with a webcam connected to my computer?

All software, that is offered in the Ubuntu Store has mentions in the ratings, that it doesen't work well.

I imagine a piece of "easy" software like this:

- an option to select the connected webcam that should be used as input
- some options to adjust brightness, ... of the webcam
- an option to select the desired frames per second for the resulting video
- a button at the bottom that can be pressed each time to take one picture for one frame of the stop motion production
- a timeline, where I can see the resulting video, with the option to mark, move and delete parts of it
- another second timeline, where I can add a track for the sound, with the same option to cut it and delete parts of it

Comment: "Easy" as compared to what?  What software, specifically, doesn't work well?  How exactly does it not work well?  Super User is not a site where people are supposed to start guessing at what you *might* want, so you can pick and choose what sounds good.  You need to provide specific and exact information.  What is Easy for me, might be impossible for you.  You provide no frame of reference.

Comment: ok, I added a vision of the perfect software

Comment: Ok.  So, to be clear, the software you have tried up to this point may have worked perfectly, but it did not have all the features you want.  You want software that is not only easy to use, and is compatible with Linux, but is most likely free... correct?  Essentially software for Linux that has all the features you would expect in an expensive suite?  You could try searching through http://www.videohelp.com

Comment: I Would also spend a bitcoin or two on a software that works fine ;)